# Are there any alternatives to making const version of class?

Tags: c++, const-correctness

In C++ I'm often facing a situation when I need to prepare const and non-const version of class in analogy to const_iterator and iterator from standard library.

```
class const_MyClass
{
  public:
      const_MyClass(const int * arr):
         m_arr(arr)
      {
      }

      int method() const;  //does something with m_arr without modifying it

  private:
      const int * m_arr;
}

class MyClass
{
  public:
      MyClass(int * arr):
         m_arr(arr)
      {
      }

      int method() const;  //does something with m_arr without modifying it

      void modify(int i);  //modify m_arr

  private:
      int * m_arr;
}
```

The problem with this is that I need to repeat whole code of `const_MyClass` in `MyClass` and distribute any changes in API to both classes. Thus sometimes I inherit `const_MyClass` and do some const_casts, which also isn't perfect and pretty solution. Still when I want to pass `const_MyClass` instance by reference it looks moronic:

```
void func(const const_MyClass & param)
```

Instance param is marked with two "consts", and it has only const methods...

This is where const constructors would be handy, but are there any existing alternatives?

---

Some use examples to explain problem better:

```
//ok to modify data
void f(int * data)
{
    MyClass my(data);
    my.modify();
    ...
}

//cant modify data, cant use MyClass
void fc(const int * data)
{
    const_MyClass my(data);
    int i = my.method();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just have `const` instances of your normal class `MyClass`?

Comment: @Galik because it will not accept `const int * arr` parameter in constructor. I can of course const_cast and bury const-correctness alive, but I try to avoid it and be const-correct...

Comment: This is just a wrapper for an external array? Then make the array type a template parameter. Not only will it now work with any type, it will accept const or non-const version too. PS try to seperate data structures from the logic which acts on them.

Comment: @NeilKirk I was/am considering it. Although in such case how to hide non-const methods from `const int *` specialization? It leads again to const version of class or weird looking additional template arguments.

Comment: Why not make `method` and `modify` normal functions that take the array as a parameter?

Comment: @NeilKirk well, of course there's always an option to replace classes with plain functions. Note that `const_iterator` is facing same problem as `const_MyClass`.

Comment: const_iterator and iterator do not directly manipulate the data, but pass the data to other code to manipulate. If your class is really analogous to iterators, you should do something similar.

Comment: @NeilKirk controversial statement as they implement operators, which affect the data they are working on. Using object instead of plain function makes code look more clear. What looks better and is more self-describing `sum(ptr1, ptr2)`  or `ptr1 += ptr2` ? You can keep state, cache etc. within class. Cumbersome to do this with plain functions. That's why I would like to have classes.

Comment: What about my statement is controversial? The operators do not alter the data, but pass it to other code for modification. I'm only basing my advice on the code you have provided.

Comment: @NeilKirk O.K. you are right, but why is that a reason other class could not behave like iterator, just provide some additional methods, some of which might have modify data?

Comment: A data structure is generic, it doesn't know how its data will be used. The logic that manipulates the data should be elsewhere. It can be in a class too, but not in the iterator class. With some more context about what you are doing, I could make a more specific suggestion.

Comment: @NeilKirk I simplified example to make it short and clean. I want to wrap pointers to provide some maths vector and matrix classes. I want to pack them inside some consistent API. Problem with raw pointers is that they even don't have information about dimension, therefore they beg for being wrapped.

Comment: @NeilKirk and I have to use pointers, because they are the way you communicate with other libraries. Everything would be perfect if not this cons-correctness :/

Comment: @NeilKirk you helped me a lot! You can take a look at my answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talk with Neil Kirk I realized what I was doing wrong. I started by separating data from logic as he suggested.

This attempt resulted in two classes `MyClassPtr` and `const_MyClassPtr`. They only provide functions for data access (like iterators) and may look like that:

```
class const_MyClassPtr
{
  public:
    const_MyClassPtr(const int * arr); 
    int operator [](int i) const;
    const int * ptr() const;

  private:
    const int * m_arr;
}

class MyClassPtr
{
  public:
    MyClassPtr(int * arr);
    int operator [](int i) const;
    int & operator [](int i);
    const int * ptr() const;
    int * ptr();
    //promotion to const pointer
    const_MyClassPtr () const {return const_MyClassPtr(m_arr);}
  private:
    int * m_arr;
}
```

Now it is clear that objects of these classes should be treated like pointers, so when I use them as function parameters I pass them by value!

```
void func(const_MyClassPtr param) //instead of void func(const const_MyClass & param)
```

To provide methods I have created `MyClassOp` class template and used static polymorphism.

```
template <class DERIVED>
class MyClassOp
{
    public:
        const DERIVED & derived() const {return static_cast<const DERIVED &>(*this)}
        DERIVED & derived() {return static_cast<DERIVED &>(*this)}
        int method() const;  //operates on derived() const
        void modify(int i);  //operates on derived()
}
```

`MyClassOp` is a collection of methods. It does not have state. In general it is a [trait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29). To make these methods accessible I overloaded `->` and `*` operators

```
class const_MyClassPtr : private MyClassOp<const_MyClassPtr>
{
   public:
    const MyClassOp<MyClassPtr> * operator ->() const {return this;}
    const MyClassOp<MyClassPtr> & operator *() const {return *this;}
    ...
}

class MyClassPtr : private MyClassOp<MyClassPtr>
{
    public:
     MyClassOp<MyClassPtr> * operator ->() {return this;}
     MyClassOp<MyClassPtr> & operator *() {return *this;}
     ...
}
```

This works O.K., but is a bit cumbersome. If I have for example equality operator I need to write something like `*myptr1 == myptr2` to compare values kept by two `MyClassPtr` objects (it's easy to make a mistake and compare `myptr1 == myptr2` or expect that something like `*myptr1 == *myptr2` could work). Also when I have allocating type:

```
class MyClass : public MyClassOp<MyClass>
{
   MyClass(int x, int y, int z);
   ...
   int m_arr[3];
}
```

I would want to be able to use temporaries as function arguments.

```
void f(const_MyClassPtr my);
//use temporary when calling f()
f(MyClass(1, 2, 3));
```

I can do this by providing conversion operators or conversion constructors (that convert `MyClass` to `const_MyClassPtr`). But then `const_MyClassPtr` behaves more like reference than pointer. If iterators are generalization of pointers then why one could not imitate reference? Therefore I divided `MyClassOp` into two parts (const and non const) and replaced `->` and `*` operators implemented by `const_MyClassPtr` and `MyClassPtr` with public inheritance and changed their names to ressemble reference. I ended up with following structures.

```
MyClassOp : public const_MyClassOp
const_MyClassRef : public const_MyClassOp<const_MyClassRef>
MyClassRef : public MyClassOp<MyClassRef>
MyClass : public MyClassOp<MyClass>
```

However `const_MyClassRef` and `MyClassRef` are not perfect generalization of reference as it impossible to imitate some of C++ reference properties, so `Ref` suffix is there to denote reference-like structure.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a template class to act as a base, like this:

```
template<typename T>
class basic_MyClass
{
  public:
      basic_MyClass(T * arr) :m_arr(arr) {}    
      int method() const;  //does something with m_arr without modifying it    
  private:
      T * m_arr;
};
```

Then, for your const version, since it doesn't add anything, you can just use a `typedef`:

```
typedef basic_MyClass<const int> const_MyClass;
```

For your non-const version, you can inherit:

```
class MyClass : public basic_MyClass<int>
{
  public:
    using basic_MyClass::basic_MyClass; // inherit all the constructors
    void modify(int i);  //modify m_arr
};
```

Comment: I'm considering something like that, except imagine `T m_arr;` instead of `T * m_arr;`. In such case you pass pointer, like in `basic_MyClass<int *>`, but you can also pass allocating type with pointer semantics `basic_MyClass<MyArray>` (and MyArray may allocate space on its own). Awesome flexibility, but probably there's no way to avoid complexity.

Comment: @doc: Sorry. I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @doc: Actually, maybe I do. At first I thought you were commenting on a potential problem or difficulty with my solution. But now I think you're just trying to imagine more interesting possibilities (for other potential problems, not necessarily the one in your question), is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply tracking two pointers and raising exceptions from the mutable operations when no mutable value is available?  Maybe an example will help describe what I am thinking of.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int *mutable_data):
        m_mutable_view(mutable_data), m_readonly_view(mutable_data) 
    {
    }

    MyClass(const int *immutable_data):
        m_mutable_view(NULL), m_readonly_view(immutable_data) 
    {
    }

    int retrieve_value(int index) {
        return m_readonly_view[index];
    }

    void set_value(int index, int value) {
        require_mutable();
        m_mutable_view[index] = value;
    }

protected:
    void require_mutable() {
        throw std::runtime_error("immutable view not available");
    }

private:
    const int *m_readonly_view;
    int *m_mutable_view;
};
```

The idea is pretty simple here - use a sentinel value to indicate whether modifications are possible or not instead of depending on the type system to do that for you.  Personally, I would think about doing the [inheritance based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26714095/41747) that @BenjaminLindley suggested but I wanted to present a slightly different solution that might not have occurred to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Believe me or not, but I was also thinking about something similar to that (only I had used union to store pointers and bool variable). I wasn't happy with the need of "extra" variable and additional checks just to be const-correct tho. I have provided answer to my own question :/ You may take a look if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can find some hints in *effective c++* item 4 *"Avoid duplication in const and non-const Member function"*

I may summarize like following ( it makes you avoid code duplication even if using somewhat ugly cast ):

```
struct my_class
{
    my_class(int x):_x(x){};

    const int& method(void) const;

    int& method(void);

    int _x;

};

const int& my_class::method(void) const   //func for const instance
{
    return _x;
}


int& my_class::method(void)         //func for normal instance
{
    return const_cast<int& >(static_cast<const my_class& >(*this).method()) ;
}




int main()
{
    my_class a(1);
    const my_class b(2);

    a.method() = 5;
    cout << a.method() << endl;

    //b.method() = 4;   //b is const, wont compile
    cout << b.method() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can write how it can be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this book. Could you provide these hints?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. [What when you have pointer or array in object?](http://rextester.com/WOA92132)